# Django form is valid if one validator is valid

Tags: django, validation

I am working on this form in django

```
class EmailOrPhoneForm(forms.Form):
      phone_or_email =  forms.CharField(
         validators=[validate_phonenumber, validate_email],
     )
```

it has two validators but I want the form to return true if one of them is valid , Phone number or Email.

how can I do this without writing a single validator that does it all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after looking into django's source code I found how they did it
in `django.core.validators` in `validate_ipv46_address` function. it applies two validators :
`validate_ipv4_address` and `validate_ipv6_address`

applying the same to my case will be.

```
def validate_email_or_phone(value):
     try:
         validate_email(value)
     except ValidationError:
         try:
             validate_phone_number(value)
         except ValidationError:
             raise ValidationError(_('Enter a valid Email address or Phone number'), code='invalid')
```

and this will be the new validator for the field

```
class EmailOrPhoneForm(forms.Form):
      phone_or_email =  forms.CharField(
         validators=[validate_email_or_phone],
     )
```

hope that helps.